# What do I search for when looking for unsweetened recipes?

Tags: sugar

This has frustrated me immensely. I want to find recipes for things like savory granola that contain neither added sugar nor any kind of sweetener like rice syrup.  However, recipes on the internet seem to include some kind of sweetener despite saying they are sugar free. Presumably they mean no added refined sugar, but sugar is sugar no matter where it comes from and I'm afraid I just don't like it. (No health reasons, I just really want to not eat sweet things sometimes).

So what do I search for? "Sugar free" gives me a bunch of artificial sweeteners recipes and "no sugar" leads me to recipes with syrups or dates or something that contains a lot of sugar anyway.

Comment: You already seem to know the answer, "*savory*" seems like the right term. Perhaps also "salty" or "salted"

Comment: Not quite. All recipes I found for savory granola had some kind of sweetener. Many other such recipes have the same problem.

Comment: what about natural sugar found in fruits ? or just no sugar at all ?

Comment: @Max: usually I find recipes that claim to be unsweetened but then contain dates or raisins or something, which is not what I want.  I'd honestly like something like toasted grains (as in the answer below).  For instance, is it possible to make an unsweetened granola bar, with herbs as flavorings, or will it just not stick together unless you have sugar?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, the correct search term is "savory."  Keep in mind, however, that while chefs often create savory versions of typically sweetened items, those versions usually have sugar or other sweeteners in them.  In granola, for example, we understand it generally as a sweet breakfast or snack item.  While the sweetness in the savory version is dramatically reduced, it is that remaining sweetness that allows us to interpret it as granola.  Otherwise, it would just be toasted grains, which, maybe in the end, is what you want.